# how get in NameForm.class.php own value?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

In template i add own input hidden?

```
<form action ....>

<input type="hidden" name="hidd" id="hidd" value="test">

<?php echo $form['name'];
echo $form['last'];
?>

</form>
```

in NameForm.class.php i can $this->getValue('name') but $this->getValue('hidd') doesnt work. how can i make this in Symfony 1.4?

Answer (score 1):

you can set in the action `$this->formName = $form->getName();` and afterwards `<?php echo $formName; ?>` in your template

Comment: and how can i get value in Name.class.php in method save? i want add this to Database

Comment: you could handle this in the `doSave()` method of your form with `$this->getObject()` you will get the current saved object, and there you should get `$this->getValue('hidd')`